# setting variable in rails module not as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When I run this code from the default module, I expect it to set the variable through an mattr_accessor:

```
Jsonforem.user_class = "User"
```

And then run `foreman start`, I get this error in my shell:

```
22:49:40 web.1  | [44763] ! Unable to load application: NoMethodError: undefined method `user_class=' for Jsonforem:Module
```

Here's the code for my module:

```
require "jsonforem/engine"

module Jsonforem

mattr_accessor :user_class, :user_profile_links, :email_from_address,
             :per_page, :sign_in_path, :moderate_first_post

def user_class
  if @@user_class.is_a?(String)
    begin
      Object.const_get(@@user_class)
    rescue NameError
      @@user_class.constantize
    end
  end
end

end
```

So far, the only way I can get it to work is like this:

```
module Jsonforem
  user_class = "User"
end
```

Why does the above code block work, but I can't set the variable from outside the module? If you need context, I am doing what is suggested here for setting config variables in your ruby gem: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Where is your module in lib directory?
Your module should be loaded before. 
Put it in config/initializers and try then.

Comment: The module is inside an included gem.

Answer (score 0):

Require solved my problem:

```
require "jsonforem"
Jsonforem.user_class = "User"
```